# Python3 UnicodeEncodeError in vscode with code runner

Tags: python, plugins, visual-studio-code, python-3.6

I am coding python3 in vscode.i install code-runner in vscode and use the plugin to run my python code.But when i wanted to print some utf8 string,there is the error.

[Running] python "/develop/python/secondLesson.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/develop/python/secondLesson.py", line 2, in 
    print('\u5475\u5475')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.049 seconds

My file is utf8,and when i run the code in my terminal , my code is OK.

Comment: You might want to try the Python Extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) for VS Code and then use the command from the Command Palette `Run Python File In Terminal`. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `your_string.encode('utf-8')`. Using your example:

```
print('\u5475\u5475'.encode('utf-8'))
```

Here's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20) explaning this in more detail.

Comment: thank you,you let me learn more about the encode of python.I add the `encode('utf-8')` and there is no error,but the console output the utf-8 in ascii:  **b'\xe5\x91\xb5\xe5\x91\xb5'**   at last ,i found the a same issue on github [link](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/25) .So it is seem a bug of the plugin of vscode. Anyway thank you to answer my question.